# logout issue after 10 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, session-timeout

I'm using .NET 4.5, and my site is logging users out after 10 minutes of inactivity, even though I have login time set to 45 minutes.

It's very frustrating for the users.

In web.config, for sessionState this is what i have:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="45">
```

and for authentication :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
```

it's hosted on **GoDaddy** whose support is useless, but it means I can't control the ***app pool recycling*** but I don't think that's the issue.

I just can't get to the bottom of it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, what makes you think they're being logged out after 10 minutes?  Your settings appear correct.  Though you have two conflicting values: 45 and 2880 are very different amounts.

Comment: Try setting the value in code-behind.

Comment: Please refer to http://forums.asp.net/t/1803857.aspx?Session+out+frequently+in+asp+net+. Have you ask Godaddy support team?

Comment: Hi, thanks - I think they are being logged out because after 10 minutes if I click a link it takes me back to the login page without an error. I have asked GoDaddy and they gave me a useless answer - they just told me how to reset the app pool manually - I'm waiting for a better one.

Comment: GoDaddy's response was: "We do recycle the application pools used within our Windows based Web Hosting plans when needed. Unfortunately, this can't be avoided when using this type of environment to my knowledge." but actually I'm not convinced this is the issue. How can I check what is happening with the timeout?

Comment: I'm still trying to troubleshoot this issue. Using Fiddler, I can see that the aspxauth cookie is created on login and is being successfully sent to the server by the browser, but after a short period of time it appears to become invalid - it's still the same auth cookie, but it doesn't allow me access to the site. I don't have access to IIS logs - does anyone have any idea why this would be?